# Transition from ViewController to SKScene

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, transition, skscene

I'm currently making a game in which the main game is a `SKScene` however the menu is a `UIViewController`. I have a button which when tapped should transition from the menu to the `SKScene`. What code should i write in the `IBAction`?

I'm running `xcode6 beta 5`. If that changes anything.

Comment: what is your code? what have you read/researched so far? what have you tried?

Comment: I have been doing big nerd ranch etc

Answer (score 0):

Simply load view controller from the storyboard. And after it present it.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *lcvc = (MyViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
lcvc.modalPresentationStyle= UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self presentViewController:lcvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I start in the actual storyboard/view controller but want to open the sprite kit file. Your code does the other way around. Can you go from view controller to sprite kit?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one view controller that contains a button and will later present the SKScene, you can implement an IBAction similar to the following:

Objective C

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    // Remove button from the view
    [button removeFromSuperview];
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Swift

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(button:UIButton)
{
    // Remove button from the view
    button.removeFromSuperview()
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

If you have two view controllers, one containing the button and the other that will present your SKScene, then you don't need an IBAction. You can simply create a segue from the button to your game view controller. From the storyboard, right-click (or control-click) on the button and drag from the Triggered Segues's action to the game view controller and release the mouse/trackpad button.